# Visualforce handler not invoked when event fired in aura component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-events, lightning-out

I'm using an aura component in a visual force page.

Aura Component:
RichInputText.cmp

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="bodyVal" type="String" />
    <!-- Events -->
    <aura:registerEvent name="RichInputTextEvent" type="c:RichInputTextEvent"/>
    <lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.bodyVal}" placeholder="Type something interesting" onblur="{!c.setHtmlBody}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Aura Event: RichInputTextEvent.evt

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
    <aura:attribute name="htmlBody" type="String" default="" access="global"/>
</aura:event>
```

I'm firing event when rich text box loose focus:
RichInputTextController.js

```
({
    setHtmlBody : function( component, event, helper ){
        var compEvent = component.getEvent("RichInputTextEvent");
        var htmlBody = component.get("v.bodyVal");
        console.log('htmlBodyAura:', htmlBody);
        compEvent.setParams({"htmlBody" : htmlBody });
        compEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Aura Application: MultipleEmailLookup.app

```
<aura:application access="global" extends ="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:MultiSelectLookup" />
    <aura:dependency resource="c:RichInputText" />
</aura:application>
```

Added handler on vf page:

```
var vfHandlerForRichTextBox = function(event){
  console.log('htmlBody: ' + event.getParam("htmlBody"));

  $Lightning.use("c:MultipleEmailLookup", function(){
    $Lightning.createComponent("c:RichInputText", {
      bodyVal: emailBody
  }, "rich-text-input", function(){
      $A.eventService.addHandler({ "event": "c:RichInputTextEvent", "handler" : vfHandlerForRichTextBox});
    });
  });
```

Handler not getting invoke when event fired in aura component.

**Update:**

I figured out I need to call the application event like this:

```
$A.get("e.c:RichInputTextEvent");
```

but now I.m getting this error on my VF page:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: c:RichInputText$controller$setHtmlBody [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setParams')] Failing descriptor: {c:RichInputText$controller$setHtmlBody}

I got solution of above error, I need to give global access to the event.

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
    <aura:attribute name="htmlBody" type="String" default="" access="global"/>
</aura:event>
```

Now the event is not undefined, but the problem still exists Visualforce handler not invoking.

Comment: Can you try instead of `component.getEvent("RichInputTextEvent");` this `$A.get("e.c:RichInputTextEvent")`?

Comment: Please my question again I have updated the issue.

Comment: what is the value of htmlBody comming  in your JS controller ?

Comment: It's showing what I type in rich text box.

Comment: in your vf page `console.log('htmlBody: ' + event.getParam("htmlBody"));` does this value comes in js console ?

Comment: No that's the actual problem that my VF handler did not invoke.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the handler method separately.

**Please change variables name with respect to your component**

```
<apex:page>
    
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="aura-cmp" />
    <script>
    
    function vfHandlerForRichTextBox(event){
        console.log(event.getParam("message"))
    }
    
    $Lightning.use("c:MultipleEmailLookup", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:RichInputText", {
            bodyVal: emailBody
        }, "rich-text-input", function(){
            $A.eventService.addHandler({ "event": "c:RichInputTextEvent", "handler" : vfHandlerForRichTextBox});
        });
        
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Tried but no success. Is it possible if my application event not firing up.

Comment: @IbrahimAhmed, I implemented from scratch same as you implemented it works for me i am able to invoke Vf Page handler. can you confirm me what is the error comming, is it the same error as this **This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: c:RichInputText$controller$setHtmlBody [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setParams')] Failing descriptor: {c:RichInputText$controller$setHtmlBody}** ?

Comment: It occurred before when I didn't give global access to the application event. After adding access="global" to the application event the error was solved but my vf handler still not invokes.

Comment: @IbrahimAhmed So now no error is comming right but the issue is your vf handler is not getting invoked ? do you see any error in console in JS

Comment: Yes, only handler not getting invoked. No errors on console.

Comment: i will edit my answer, for new solution please try and let me know if it helped

Comment: when are you calling your vfHandlerForRichTextBox()  method ?

Comment: I'm expecting it will be automatically called when event fired:
`$A.eventService.addHandler({ "event": "c:RichInputTextEvent", "handler" : vfHandlerForRichTextBox});`

Comment: No it won’t automatically fires we have to catch the event in our ‘eventService.addHandler’ then assign a handler function that handles the value . You have to differentiate the handler function don’t initialise your aura cmp inside of it the handler function, initialisation of the aura cmp need to be separate not in a handler function . I have edited my answers added updated code try like that

Comment: I'm already doing like this what you have done in the update.

Comment: vfHandlerForRichTextBox() i have defined seperately

and in global scope i have kept `$Lightning.use("c:MultipleEmailLookup", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:RichInputText", {
            bodyVal: emailBody
        }, "rich-text-input", function(){
            $A.eventService.addHandler({ "event": "c:RichInputTextEvent", "handler" : vfHandlerForRichTextBox});
        });
        
    });`